Upload video to storage firebase gives error

flutter: Day schedule: {workout_videos: [{id: 1730307023026, repetitions: 0, sets: 0, name: New Workout Video, videoUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/influfit-619fa.appspot.com/o/workout_videos%2Fimage_picker_6F1DD127-0A8F-46DA-A346-31A5128CE5A4-33508-000009F3E6DF44A2trim.E2162C59-B439-48A6-BC49-44F8B149F82F.MOV?alt=media&token=d55243a2-4406-4d1b-b73a-dadf2294a4f2}], day: Monday, ordinal: 1st, estimatedKcal: 20}
flutter: Workout videos loaded: [{id: 1730307023026, repetitions: 0, sets: 0, name: New Workout Video, videoUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/influfit-619fa.appspot.com/o/workout_videos%2Fimage_picker_6F1DD127-0A8F-46DA-A346-31A5128CE5A4-33508-000009F3E6DF44A2trim.E2162C59-B439-48A6-BC49-44F8B149F82F.MOV?alt=media&token=d55243a2-4406-4d1b-b73a-dadf2294a4f2}]
flutter: Initializing video player with URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/influfit-619fa.appspot.com/o/workout_videos%2Fimage_picker_6F1DD127-0A8F-46DA-A346-31A5128CE5A4-33508-000009F3E6DF44A2trim.E2162C59-B439-48A6-BC49-44F8B149F82F.MOV?alt=media&token=d55243a2-4406-4d1b-b73a-dadf2294a4f2
flutter: Video URL status code: 200
flutter: Error initializing video player: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)

I am trying to upload video to firebase and be able to see it after upload in the Ui. The app is made in flutter but I get an error after I uploaded and it can not be load( I don't know if it's from initialisation or is there another error).
Here is the ui after I press the add button and choose a video :enter image description here
Here is the code for it :
class VideoContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String day;
  final bool allowEditing;
  final String programId;
  final int scheduleIndex;

  const VideoContent({
    Key? key,
    required this.day,
    required this.allowEditing,
    required this.programId,
    required this.scheduleIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoContentState createState() => _VideoContentState();
}

class _VideoContentState extends State<VideoContent> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final uuid = Uuid();
  List<dynamic> workoutVideos = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  String errorMessage = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadWorkoutVideos();
  }

  Future<void> _loadWorkoutVideos() async {
    try {
      print('Loading workout videos for ${widget.day} in program ${widget.programId}');
      final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).get();
      
      if (!doc.exists) {
        throw Exception('Program document does not exist');
      }

      final programData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print('Program data: $programData');

      if (!programData.containsKey('workout_schedule')) {
        throw Exception('workout_schedule field is missing in the program document');
      }

      final workoutSchedule = programData['workout_schedule'] as List<dynamic>;
      print('Workout schedule: $workoutSchedule');

      if (widget.scheduleIndex < workoutSchedule.length) {
        final daySchedule = workoutSchedule[widget.scheduleIndex];
        print('Day schedule: $daySchedule');

        // Create an empty workout_videos array if it doesn't exist
        if (!daySchedule.containsKey('workout_videos')) {
          print('Creating empty workout_videos array for this day');
          daySchedule['workout_videos'] = [];
          
          // Update Firestore with the new empty workout_videos array
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).update({
            'workout_schedule': workoutSchedule,
          });
        }

        setState(() {
          workoutVideos = daySchedule['workout_videos'] ?? [];
          isLoading = false;
        });
        print('Workout videos loaded: $workoutVideos');
      } else {
        throw Exception('Invalid schedule index');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading workout videos: $e');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        errorMessage = 'Error loading workout videos: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateWorkoutVideo(int index, Map<String, dynamic> updatedVideo) async {
    setState(() {
      workoutVideos[index] = updatedVideo;
    });
    await _updateFirestore();
  }

  Future<void> _updateFirestore() async {
    try {
      final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).get();
      final programData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final workoutSchedule = programData['workout_schedule'] as List<dynamic>;
      
      workoutSchedule[widget.scheduleIndex]['workout_videos'] = workoutVideos;

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc(widget.programId).update({
        'workout_schedule': workoutSchedule,
      });

      print('Firestore updated successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error updating Firestore: $e');
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = 'Error updating workout: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _addWorkoutVideo() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? video = await _picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (video != null) {
      File videoFile = File(video.path);
      String fileName = path.basename(videoFile.path);
      String videoUrl = await _uploadVideoToFirebase(videoFile, fileName);

      final newVideo = {
        'id': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
        'name': 'New Workout Video',
        'videoUrl': videoUrl,
        'repetitions': 0,
        'sets': 0,
      };

      setState(() {
        workoutVideos.add(newVideo);
      });

      await _updateFirestore();
    }
  }

  Future<String> _uploadVideoToFirebase(File videoFile, String fileName) async {
    try {
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
      Reference ref = storage.ref().child('workout_videos/$fileName');

      final fileLength = await videoFile.length();
      final chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk size
      final totalChunks = (fileLength / chunkSize).ceil();

      final uploadTask = ref.putData(Uint8List(0));
      final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;

      for (var i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
        final start = i * chunkSize;
        final end = min((i + 1) * chunkSize, fileLength);
        final bytes = await videoFile.openRead(start, end).toList();
        final chunk = Uint8List.fromList(bytes.expand((x) => x).toList());

        final uploadTask = ref.putData(
          chunk,
          SettableMetadata(
            contentType: 'video/mp4',
            customMetadata: {'chunk': i.toString(), 'chunks': totalChunks.toString()},
          ),
        );

        uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
          final progress = ((i / totalChunks) + (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) / totalChunks) * 100;
          print('Upload progress: ${progress.toStringAsFixed(2)}%');
        }, onError: (e) {
          print('Upload error: $e');
        });

        await uploadTask;
      }

      // Get the download URL
      String downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadUrl;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error uploading video: $e');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to upload video. Please try again.')),
      );
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteWorkoutVideo(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      workoutVideos.removeAt(index);
    });

    await _updateFirestore();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.day),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : errorMessage.isNotEmpty
              ? Center(child: Text(errorMessage, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)))
              : workoutVideos.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'No workout videos available for this day.\nTap the + button to add a video.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                      ),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: workoutVideos.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final video = workoutVideos[index];
                        return WorkoutVideoItem(
                          video: video,
                          onUpdate: (updatedVideo) => _updateWorkoutVideo(index, updatedVideo),
                          onDelete: () => _deleteWorkoutVideo(index),
                          allowEditing: widget.allowEditing,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
      floatingActionButton: widget.allowEditing
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _addWorkoutVideo,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
}

class WorkoutVideoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> video;
  final Function(Map<String, dynamic>) onUpdate;
  final VoidCallback onDelete;
  final bool allowEditing;

  const WorkoutVideoItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.video,
    required this.onUpdate,
    required this.onDelete,
    required this.allowEditing,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WorkoutVideoItemState createState() => _WorkoutVideoItemState();
}

class _WorkoutVideoItemState extends State<WorkoutVideoItem> {
  VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;
  late TextEditingController _nameController;
  late TextEditingController _repsController;
  late TextEditingController _setsController;
  bool _isVideoLoaded = false;
  bool _isVideoError = false;
  bool _isUploading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.video['name']);
    _repsController = TextEditingController(text: widget.video['repetitions'].toString());
    _setsController = TextEditingController(text: widget.video['sets'].toString());
    _initializeVideoPlayer();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    print('Initializing video player with URL: ${widget.video['videoUrl']}');
    
    try {
      // Dispose existing controllers if they exist
      await _disposeControllers();

      bool isAccessible = await _isVideoUrlAccessible(widget.video['videoUrl']);
      if (!isAccessible) {
        throw Exception('Video URL is not accessible');
      }

      _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        widget.video['videoUrl'],
        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
      );

      await _videoPlayerController?.initialize().timeout(
        Duration(seconds: 15),
        onTimeout: () => throw Exception('Video initialization timeout'),
      );
      
      print('Video player initialized successfully');
      
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isVideoLoaded = true;
          _isVideoError = false;
          if (_videoPlayerController != null) {
            _chewieController = ChewieController(
              videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController!,
              aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
              autoPlay: false,
              looping: false,
              errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
                print('Chewie error: $errorMessage');
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Error: $errorMessage',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error initializing video player: $error');
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isVideoLoaded = false;
          _isVideoError = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _disposeControllers() async {
    await _videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController = null;
    _chewieController = null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disposeControllers();
    _nameController.dispose();
    _repsController.dispose();
    _setsController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _pickVideo() async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? video = await _picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (video != null) {
      setState(() {
        _isUploading = true;
      });

      try {
        // Add video format validation
        final String extension = path.extension(video.path).toLowerCase();
        if (!['.mp4', '.mov', '.avi'].contains(extension)) {
          throw Exception('Unsupported video format. Please use MP4, MOV, or AVI formats.');
        }

        // Compress the video with error handling
        print('Starting video compression');
        final MediaInfo? compressedVideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
          video.path,
          quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
          deleteOrigin: false,
          includeAudio: true,
          frameRate: 30, // Add specific frame rate
        );

        if (compressedVideo?.file == null) {
          throw Exception('Video compression failed');
        }

        print('Video compressed successfully. New size: ${compressedVideo!.filesize} bytes');

        // Validate compressed video
        final File videoFile = File(compressedVideo.file!.path);
        if (!await videoFile.exists()) {
          throw Exception('Compressed video file not found');
        }

        // Generate a simpler filename
        final String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        final String fileName = 'video_$timestamp.mp4';
        
        print('Uploading compressed video: ${compressedVideo.file!.path}');
        print('Generated file name: $fileName');

        String videoUrl = await (context.findAncestorStateOfType<_VideoContentState>()
            ?._uploadVideoToFirebase(videoFile, fileName) ?? Future.value(''));

        print('Video uploaded successfully. URL: $videoUrl');

        // Add delay before initializing player
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

        // Verify the uploaded file with timeout
        bool isAccessible = await _isVideoUrlAccessible(videoUrl)
            .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () => false);
        
        if (!isAccessible) {
          throw Exception('Uploaded video is not accessible');
        }

        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            final updatedVideo = {
              ...widget.video,
              'videoUrl': videoUrl,
            };
            widget.onUpdate(updatedVideo);
          });

          // Reinitialize video player with error handling
          await _initializeVideoPlayer().timeout(
            Duration(seconds: 15),
            onTimeout: () => throw Exception('Video player initialization timeout'),
          );
          
          setState(() {});
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error processing video: $e');
        if (mounted) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('Error: ${e.toString()}'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
            ),
          );
        }
      } finally {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _isUploading = false;
          });
        }
        await VideoCompress.deleteAllCache();
      }
    }
  }

  String _generateShortFileName(String filePath) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(filePath);
    final hash = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return hash.toString().substring(0, 8) + '.mp4';
  }

  void _updateVideo() {
    final updatedVideo = {
      ...widget.video,
      'name': _nameController.text,
      'repetitions': int.tryParse(_repsController.text) ?? 0,
      'sets': int.tryParse(_setsController.text) ?? 0,
    };
    widget.onUpdate(updatedVideo);
  }

  void _showVideoPreview(BuildContext context) {
    if (_chewieController == null) return;
    
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
            child: Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController!,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: _isVideoLoaded ? () => _showVideoPreview(context) : null,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: _isVideoLoaded && _videoPlayerController != null
                        ? AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                            child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController!),
                          )
                        : _isVideoError
                            ? Container(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red)),
                              )
                            : Container(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 16),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      widget.allowEditing
                          ? TextField(
                              controller: _nameController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Workout Name'),
                            )
                          : Text(widget.video['name'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: widget.allowEditing
                                ? TextField(
                                    controller: _repsController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Reps'),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  )
                                : Text('Reps: ${widget.video['repetitions']}'),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 16),
                          Expanded(
                            child: widget.allowEditing
                                ? TextField(
                                    controller: _setsController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Sets'),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  )
                                : Text('Sets: ${widget.video['sets']}'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                if (widget.allowEditing)
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                    onPressed: widget.onDelete,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
            if (widget.allowEditing)
              _isUploading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: _updateVideo,
                        child: Text('Save Changes'),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: _pickVideo,
                        child: Text('Change Video'),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<bool> _isVideoUrlAccessible(String url) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.head(Uri.parse(url)).timeout(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      onTimeout: () => throw Exception('Connection timeout'),
    );
    print('Video URL status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    return response.statusCode == 200;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error checking video URL: $e');
    return false;
  }
}


"I get an error after I uploaded" What error? Please edit your question to include the exact error message (copy/paste) and stack trace (both as text, no screenshots please).

please don't put firebase hashtags anymore because no one answers when I add them

If Firebase/Firestore is relevant to the problem, the question should be tagged with it. If it isn't relevant to the problem, create a minimal repro that doesn't use Firebase/Firestore.

Thanks for the additional logging info. That URL shows an empty video player for me btw when I open it in a Chrome tab.

yes because probably my compressing method for the video that is over 5sec is wrong

There is far too much going on here that can be the cause of the problem. If the video compression is the problem, you should be able to reproduce the problem without uploading the compressed video to Firebase. Creating a minimal repro makes it much more likely someone can help, and also means you can get rid of the Firebase tags that you think are affecting people's willingness to answer. Also see: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
